# The photos timeline requires Plex Media Server 1.5.4 or higher

Tags: synology, plex

I have just installed the Plex server for the first time on my Synology NAS DS918+. Then I tried to add a few photo libraries and I tried to choose different directories with photos (mostly JPG). When I go to library from web application, it says "The photos timeline requires Plex Media Server 1.5.4 or higher". There is a link also with caption "Browse by type", if I click this link it says `There are no items in this library`.

I have tried many photo directories, and I tried it with chrome and safari as I use Mac, but same results. Here is the version information.

Plex server: `1.9.7.4460-a39b25852` 
Web application (in browser): `3.26.2`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

For me it was a permission issue. Not knowing what user account the Plex operates under I gave read permission to the media folder to "Everyone" and that solved it.